# Model validation failed when creatung the simplest WebACL

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I bumped into this error.

```
Resource handler returned message: "Model validation failed (#/DefaultAction/Block/CustomResponse/ResponseCode: failed validation constraint for keyword [minimum]
)" (RequestToken: c97b2cae-821a-2be3-465a-965164d34674, HandlerErrorCode: InvalidRequest)
```

I am trying to make the simplest `WAF` for my first scratch.

```
const wafacl = new wafv2.CfnWebACL(this, "MyCfnWebAll",{
  scope: "REGIONAL",
  defaultAction: {
    allow:{
      customRequestHandling: {
        insertHeaders: [{
          name: 'name',
          value: 'value',
        }],
      },
    },
    block: {
      customResponse: {
        responseCode: 123,
        customResponseBodyKey: 'customResponseBodyKey',
        responseHeaders: [{
          name: 'name',
          value: 'value',
        }],
      },
    }
  },
  visibilityConfig:{
    cloudWatchMetricsEnabled: false,
    metricName: 'metricName',
    sampledRequestsEnabled: false
  }
});
```

My goal is just make the simple `WAF` and connect this to `ALB`.

Could someone help my first step?

Comment: WAF does not like your `responseCode: 123`.  It's not on the list of [Supported status codes for custom response](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/customizing-the-response-status-codes.html).

Comment: Thank you I chaged here `123` -> `400` and error changed  `"Error reason: You have used none or multiple values for a field that requires exactly one va
lue., field: DEFAULT_ACTION,`

Comment: I omit `block`  and it works!